# Type conversion between two similar Datatable objects

Tags: c#, .net, casting, type-conversion

I have .NET project with sync framework and two separate Datasets for MS SQL and Compact SQL. in my base class I have a generic DataTable object. in my derived classed I assign Typed DataTable to the generic object based on whether the application is operating online or offline: example:

```
if (online)
    _dataTable = new MSSQLDataSet.Customer;
else
    _dataTable = new CompactSQLDataSet.Customer;
```

Now every where in my code i have to check and do a cast based on the current network mode like this:

```
public void changeCustomerID(int ID)
{
    if (online)
        (MSSQLDataSet.CustomerDataTable)_dataTable)[i].CustomerID = value;
    else
        (CompactMSSQLDataSet.CustomerDataTable)_dataTable)[i].CustomerID = value;
 }
```

but I don't think this is very efficient and I believe it can be done in a smarter way to only use one line of code by dynamically getting the Type of _dataTable on the run time.

my problem is at the design time,  in order to acess datatable porperties such as "CustomerID" it has to be casted to either MSSQLDataSet.CustomerDataTable or CompactMSSQLDataSet.CustomerDataTable.

Is there a way to have a function or a operator to convert the _datatable to its runtime type but still be able to use it's design time properties which are the same between the two types? something like:

```
((aType)_dataTable)[i].CustomerID = value;
//or 
GetRuntimeType(_dataTable)[i].CustomerID = value;
```

Comment: use a ICustomerDataTable interface ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate your Dataset from your TableAdapters. You should have ONE dataset (with the corresponding table definitions) and two sets of table adapters: one for SQL an the other for SQL CE.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384570.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the advice, sounds like a good practice, however I just decided to stick with my initial design for this project.

Answer (score 0):

**Seperate your DataSet as Y. Ecarri wrote earlier.**

If this isn't possible for you, you can use a Decorator pattern to wrapp the Data. (Not recommended!)

```
public interface ICustomer{
    ICustomerData GetCustomerData(int index);
}

public interface ICustomerData{
    int CustomerId{ get; }
}

public class OnlineCustomer : ICustomer{

    private MSSQLDataSet.Customer innerCustomer;

    public OnlineCustomer(MSSQLDataSet.Customer innerCustomer){
        this.innerCustomer = innerCustomer;
    }
    ICustomerData GetCustomerData(int index){
        return new OnlineCustomerData(innerCustomer[index]);
    }
}

public class OnlineCustomerData : ICustomerData{
    private MSSQLDataSet.CustomerDataTable innerCustomer;
    public OnlineCustomerData(MSSQLDataSet.CustomerDataTable innerCustomer){
        this.innerCustomer = innerCustomer;
    }

    public int CustomerId{
        get {
            return innerCustomer.CustomerId;
        }
    }
}

public class OfflineCustomerData : ICustomerData{
    private CompactSQLDataSet.CustomerDataTable innerCustomer;
    public OfflineCustomerData(CompactSQLDataSet.CustomerDataTable innerCustomer){
        this.innerCustomer = innerCustomer;
    }

    public int CustomerId{
        get {
            return innerCustomer.CustomerId;
        }
    }
}

public class OfflineCustomer : ICustomer{

    private CompactSQLDataSet.Customer innerCustomer;

    public OfflineCustomer(CompactSQLDataSet.Customer innerCustomer){
        this.innerCustomer = innerCustomer;
    }
    ICustomerData GetCustomerData(int index){
        return new OfflineCustomerData(innerCustomer[index]);
    }
}

public class Program{
    private ICustomer customer;

    public  ICustomer Customer{
        get{
            if(customer == null)
                customer = CreateCustomer();
            retrun customer;
        }
    }

    public ICustomerData CreateCustomer(){
        if(online){
            new OnlineCustomer(new MSSQLDataSet.Customer);
        } else {
           new OfflineCustomer(new CompactSQLDataSet.Customer);
        }
    }

    public void Usage(){
        ICustomerData data12 = Customer.GetCustomerData(12);
        int id = data12.CustomerId;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but this seemed too big of a job for my project.